# Couldn't Excute command line PostGIS pgsql2shp

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, postgresql

I am using postgres 9.3 with postgis 2.1 on Ubuntu 14. When I tried to dump pgsql table using pgsql2shp, I get the following error.

```
Error: pg_wrapper: pgsql2shp was not found in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin
```

The command I used is the following.

```
pgsql2shp -f "/home/user/testshp.shp" -h localhost -u postgres -P postgres  dbname "SELECT * FROM table"
```

In  `sudo nano /etc/environment` I have added,`:/usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp`

I also also created a link using a guide from [here](https://geekforum.wordpress.com/2014/05/06/install-and-run-postgresql-postgis-and-opengeo/).

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```

Is any the things I did causing the problem? Is there any solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Exactly how did you change `/etc/environment`? Please note that the default PATH includes `/usr/local/bin`, and if you put a symlink in that folder, it should work without further changes.

Comment: In terminal I typed `sudo nano /etc/environment` and added `:/usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp` And also the two other postgis tools. Then in terminal I typed `source /etc/environment`. How could I do the symbolic link and to what. I have done it already as seen on the question. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Your edit of `/etc/environment` was redundant. PATH should contain a list of folders, not files, and `/usr/local/bin` is already there.

Comment: Oh yes, that is true. However, after removing them, I still get the same error message. The files are located in `/usr/local/bin/` but the error message says pg_wrapper: pgsql2shp are not found in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin . It is tricky for me what to link with what.

Comment: What you say indicates that the problem lies in the settings of that **pgsql2shp** program. Somehow it seems to call itself, and then presupposes that it's located in the folder mentioned in the error message. Possibly a symlink also there might make a difference.

Comment: I see. So you mean linking the file with a link in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was all about the **unneeded** symbolic link.

```
 sudo ln -sf /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
```

I fixed the issue finally by just removing the symbolic links.

```
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/shp2pgsql
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/pgsql2shp
 sudo rm /usr/local/bin/raster2pgsql
```

Then removed postgis 2.1 with

```
 sudo apt-get remove postgis-2.1
 sudo apt-get remove postgresql-9.4-postgis-2.1
```

Then installed postgis again by

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
 sudo apt-get update 
 sudo apt-get install postgis
```

Thank you Gunnar Hjalmarsson for the help!

Comment: Glad that you fixed it. Despite my comments it sems. ;)

Comment: They were helpful comments :)